# Get the values of a child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

root

```
-messages
   --LIB38128eG7v
      -receiverID: "yoon"
      -senderID: "kim"
      -text: "good day"
   --LIB36334eG9e
      -receiverID: "yoon"
      -senderID: "kim"
      -text: "good night"
```

this is my firebase database.
and there is a class named `Chat`, which has `receiverID`, `senderID`, `text`.
I can get all the data of messages by

```
ref.child("messages").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){
   public void onChildAdded(Datasnapshot dataSnapshot, String s){
   Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
   mChat.add(chat); //mChat is an array of Chat
 ....
}
```

But I want to get the data of `LIB38128eG7v`, not the all of the messages. In this case, how can I get one of the child's child values?
Is there any way not using listener?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the data from a Firebase database without using a listener. Everything in Firebase is about listeners. To get the data under `-LIB38128eG7v`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference messageIdRef = rootRef.child("messages").child("-LIB38128eG7v");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
        Log.d("TAG", chat.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
messageIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be: `good day`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way it will work

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages").child("- 
LIB38128eG7v");
 rootRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        //your code
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```